# It or them: How to refer to a single noun followed by any with a pronoun?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, determiners, any-every

Is the sentence below correct?

I want to say I can't merely rely on self-learning in order to become proficient in my career, and I need better resources.

> Although self-learning is an essential factor of success for any career, I believe it isn’t enough to achieve full mastery in **them**.

Or do I have to say it this way:

> Although self-learning is an essential factor of success for any career, I believe it isn’t enough to achieve full mastery in **it**.

However, as both sound a bit awkward to me, I would appreciate it if anyone could suggest me better substitutes.

Comment: I think your second example is closer, but both are still awkward. What exactly are you trying to get across? Could you give some more context?

Comment: @Chromane I agree. I want to say I can't merely rely on self-learning in order to become proficient in my career, and I need better resources.

Comment: Which noun represents the thing you want to master? The syntax suggests ‘career’, but that’s not something normally described as a thing to be mastered.

Comment: "I believe it isn’t enough to achieve full mastery in **one**."

Comment: If you're gonna use _mastery_, it should be _mastery **of**_, not _in_.

Comment: I would simply leave the last two words out. They are not necessary; the sense is clear without them, and the sentence reads much better.

Comment: So 'mastery of one'.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Right, that makes sense and it sounds much better! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Lawrence: Then, are there some other words we can use to express the same meaning for a career, using an equivalent or similar syntactic structure to the original "[noun (viz. *mastery*)] + *in/of* + [noun/pronoun]"?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed What do you mean by the 'mastery' of a career?

Comment: @Lawrence I mean "being very effective in obtaining the desired results in the job". (By the way, were you going for the Socratic Method just now or were you simply confused?)

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed That's "becoming good at what you do", or perhaps "mastering a technique".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second example is closer, but both are still awkward. Maybe other terms for "Self-learning"?

In both sentences it is unclear whether "mastery" refers to the skill of self-learning or the field itself.

- Self-learning is a valuable skill in any career, but true mastery requires proper resources and support
- While independent learning and self-directed growth are important, true proficiency in a skill or field requires feedback and support.

Comment: Wow, this sounds much better. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Nice answer. I have a question: Re your second suggestion here, do you see a difference in meaning between "independent learning" and "self-directed growth", or did you explicitly mention them both for some stylistic reason?